# Preg Match a string with $, numbers, and letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to preg_match this string.

```
$word = "$1$s"; 
or 
$word = "$2$s"

if(preg_match('/^\$[1-9]{1}\$s$/' ,$word)){
   echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

I tried this but it is not giving a true result.
How can I make this true.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? :/

Comment: I meant, I'm trying to make this true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is trying to [render the variable `$s` in the double quoted string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).  Use single quotes instead and you can remove the `{1}` inside your regular expression because it is not necessary.

```
$word = '$1$s';

if (preg_match('/^\$[1-9]\$s$/', $word)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

You can also escape the `$` in your double quoted string:

```
$word = "$1\$s";
// Note $1 doesn't need to be escaped since variables can't start with numbers
```

Finally, you can see why this wasn't working by seeing what your `$word` actually equaled (with error reporting enabled):

```
$word = "$1$s"; // Notice: Undefined variable: s on line #
echo $word;     // $1
```

Comment: Side note: you had me scratching my head for a good 5 minutes on this one..its funny the little things that cause big problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/\$[1-9]{1}\$s/',$word)){
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: That's basically the same regular expression as in the question with the only difference that it doesn't check whether the match extends to the beginning and end of the string.